# binary search tree, non recursive using stack

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, stack, binary-search-tree

What should I know about having two separate classes in one .h file?

I have a binary search tree class with all the members and public & private functions.

```
class BinarySearchTree
{
   struct Node {
      Node* left;
      Node* right;
      int val;
   };
};
```

and following that code I want to design a stack of pointers to that binary search tree node. Within the same.h file I have

```
class stack
{
  Node* array;
  //

};
```

Visual Studio doesn't show linkage and doesn't recognize `Node*`. Is it ok to declare two separate classes in one .h file or is it better to implement the stack class nested inside the binary search tree class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared a `struct` called `Node` that is nested in the class `BinarySearchTree`, so if you want to refer to that `struct` outside of the class, you need to refer to it like this:

```
class stack
{
  BinarySearchTree::Node* array;
  //

};
```

Whether or not that's good design is a whole new question, so I would recommend getting a bit further with the implementation before asking more.

**EDIT**

Like you noticed, it's necessary to make the nested struct `public` if you want to use it outside of the class. That, in itself, is not necessarily bad or wrong. You're not exposing data, just a declaration.

You've got two choices:

1. Make the nested struct public.
2. Take the nested struct outside of the enclosing class.

Personally, I'd go for the first option.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but the Node is declared private. I tried what you suggested and VS recognizes the linkage but shows error: is inaccessible. but I don't think it is a good idea to declare the node as public. @RogerRowland Thanks before.

Comment: Ah, so you *did* get a bit further ;-)

Comment: Yeah. Since I'm only asked only for 1 .h file, would you think implementing stack class nested is A OK? @RogerRowland

Comment: Thanks. I will do as you suggested. I appreciate your help! @RogerRowland

Comment: I used inheritance and make the BST as the base class for the derived stack class. and I declared the struct protected thus making the Node inaccessible directly to users. Do you think that's a good idea? Thanks @RogerRowland

Comment: A third option would be making `stack` a friend.